# Cannot get current monitor to work when charging battery

Tags: current-measurement

I have built a small boost converter and current limit circuit to enable me to charge a LiFePo4 battery pack. (circuit diagram attached). This works great and I can charge from a 12V-18V supply with a 1.0A limit. I only charge the battery in constant current mode up to the max voltage level for the batteries. I was ok with this as it gets me most of the battery capacity I need, maybe 90%.

I then added a current monitor using a MAX9938 IC which I have used successfully in other circuits. I wanted to continue charging the battery in constant voltage mode, while monitoring the current, to take the final charge level closer to 100%.

The current monitor part doesn't work. Output voltage is always low (under 0.3V) and it should be 3.0V for a 0.12 ohm sense resistor with 1A current using the Gain = 25 IC I am using. I have varied the sense resistor, tried different MAX9938s in case of damage, tried different current monitor ICs (ZXCT1107), all with the same result. In all these scenarios the actual measured charge current is stable at 1.0A. The MAX9938 is operating near its 30V max though I have used it in 29V situations before. The ZCT1107 is rated to 40V and displays the same behaviour.

I must be doing something stupid with the circuit, but I can't see it. Any general or even specific thoughts or advice would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this, it could be a physical issue. Have you checked the circuit in situ? Do all the pins of the amp have voltages present as you expect?

Comment: Accidentially swapped RS+ and RS-?

Comment: thanks Jens . I did check and RS+/RS- are the correct way around

thanks also LordTeddy . I will keep checking the physical layout and hope I trip over something